# Was Leiber's "The Sunken Land" influenced by C. A. Smith's "The Vaults of Yoh-Vombis"?

Tags: fritz-leiber, clark-ashton-smith, lankhmar

As I was re-reading "[The Vaults of Yoh-Vombis](http://www.eldritchdark.com/writings/short-stories/231/the-vaults-of-yoh-vombis)" by Clark Ashton Smith, I noticed some surprising similarities to another fantasy classic, "[The Sunken Land](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?57321)," by Fritz Leiber.  Obviously, there are many differences between the two tales, but they both feature

- Exploration of a ancient, apparently lifeless city (hardly an uncommon situation in SF and fantasy)
- Opening a special door, behind with the monsters still occupying the ruins dwell
- The explorers being devoured, except for the protagonist, by *flat, floppy monsters*.

Leiber's story was written about a decade after Smith's, so I wonder whether Leiber ever indicated he was influenced by the earlier tale.

Comment: Author tags are used for questions exclusively about the authors, if you have a work you want to ask about create a work tag: [Relevant meta policy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7924/68872), and [another reasonable consensus](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4861/68872)